# Timestamp and Autolock every 1 hours after data input

Tags: typescript, google-sheets, timestamp, codeblocks

I need help with my Google Sheets document script: I need to auto timestamp and auto-lock a column 1 hour after input data at column A if I input data at column I.
Help me to write the script.

This is my document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18KlQhsXD_TDl5yraF-0Endz-4KQCBLTlm0Rgxr5H5-Y/edit#gid=0

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jchien, thanks for your question. We can't access a private Google Document, nor do I recommend sharing that publically. Try sharing a screenshot of your spreadsheet and provide a code-block of anything you have attempted as far as the script goes.

Comment: Is there a code you are working on? Please consider providing a sample spreadsheet, free of sensitive information, that is publicly accessible, clearly indicating the expected output.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18KlQhsXD_TDl5yraF-0Endz-4KQCBLTlm0Rgxr5H5-Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: help me to write script at my docment. thank you..

Comment: The spreadsheet you provided has restricted access. Can you make it publicly accessible? (of course, remove private information).

Comment: i already open this document to edit. thankyou